# lvalue required as left operand of assignment in some old c code

Tags: c

Why is the second line of the  following code throwing a C error : lvalue required as left operand of assignment

```
  if (!str_cmp( type, "obj")){
    if ( ((OBJ_DATA*) tar = get_obj_here( NULL, room, target)) == NULL){
      bug("prog_destroy: obj target not found.", 0);
      return;
    }
    else{
      list = (OBJ_DATA*) tar;
      list = list->contains;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast on the LHS of an assignment.
I.e. `(OBJ_DATA*)` tar is not allowed on the second line.

You can try declaring `OBJ_DATA * tar = NULL;` then using it as

```
tar = get_obj_here( NULL, room, target)
```

or

```
tar =(OBJ_DATA*) get_obj_here( NULL, room, target)
```

depending on what `get_obj_here()` returns.

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365153/what-happens-when-a-casted-pointer-has-an-increment-operator

Comment: *Typecast* should be *cast*.

Answer (score 2):

Casting results in a r-value. It can't be done on the left side (l-value) of `=` operator.

```
if ( ((OBJ_DATA*) tar = get_obj_here( NULL, room, target)) == NULL)  
        ^
        |
   Remove this data type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's an error in the code.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057728/casting-error-lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment?rq=1),

> You cannot cast the left operand of the assignment operator in C.

And this [question (Casting a pointer does not produce an lvalue. Why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why?rq=1) goes into more detail.

> The underlying reason is that all these things, including your cast,
>   create a new value. Casting a value to the type it already is,
>   likewise creates a new value, never mind whether pointers to different
>   types have the same representation or not. In some cases, the new
>   value happens to be equal to the old value, but in principle it's a
>   new value, it's not intended to be used as a reference to the old
>   object, and that's why it's an rvalue.
>
> For these to be lvalues, the standard would have to add some special
>   cases that certain operations when used on an lvalue result in a
>   reference to the old object, instead of a new value. AFAIK there's no
>   great demand for those special cases.

Comment: If I remember correctly, such operations were allowed in Turbo-C.

Comment: @alk: also on older GCC versions.